# can any one tell why this save button is not enable after entering the document data?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

I am working on Firebase and I am a beginner in Firebase. I want to use Firebase a back end service as well as store the data with react Js.I created the project.I select the Firestore database and create the collection. I come to the document window where I enter the field name and value of the field.But why after entering the value and field the save button is not enabled ?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that behavior because you didn't assign an ID to the document you want to create. To solve this, simply press "Auto-ID" or type any ID of your choice and the "save" button will be enabled.

Comment: Iam facing the same even after selecting Auto-Id its still disabled.

Comment: I too am facing the same issue: I clicked Auto-ID, but the save button is still disabled. Tried different browsers, incognito mode, clearing the cache, but no luck. Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

After typing id press enter. It will be added

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This happen to me, the solution for me are open Firebase/Firestone on Google Chrome, and make sure you put a Document ID.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this happend to me for the first time. When I add some random data in 'value' field, save was enabled. Next time on wards everything was working
as expected.